# Image showing up on wrong screen in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

im relatively new to coding and am trying to display an image on tkinter, i have it set so when you press on a button on the first screen it will open to another screen - i have got this working fine my issue is that when the new window is opened the image that should be on the second screen goes onto the first screen, and i cannot work out how to fix it. I dont get any errors it just puts the image in the middle of the first screen, I hope this makes sense. Thanks

The code is below: (for the second screen that should be displaying the image but isnt)

```
from tkinter import *



window2 = Tk()
window2.geometry("1920x1200")

Namearea = Label(window2, text = "Please Name the Prebuild: ")

Namearea.pack()

e = Entry(window2, width=50, borderwidth=3, bg="Light Grey", fg="black")
e.pack()
e.insert(0, "Remove this text and Enter the name of your prebuild: ")


# this is the part for the image    
img3 = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Tkinter\ComputerImage.png ")
picture1 = Label(image=img3)
picture1.pack()



SaveAndContinue = Button(window2, text = "Save and Return to Main Menu", padx = 75, pady = 20, bg = "Light Grey")

SaveAndContinue.pack()


LinkTitle = Label(window2, text = "Here are some links to purchase the parts from:")
Link1 = Label(window2, text = "Scorptec: www.scorptec.com.au/")
Link2 = Label(window2, text = "Centre-Com: www.centrecom.com.au/")


LinkTitle.pack()
Link1.pack()
Link2.pack()
```

Comment: You did not specify the parent for the label `picture1`, so it will be assigned to first instance of `Tk()` which I think is the first window.  Should be `picture1 = Label(window2, image=img3)`.  However, multiple instances of `Tk()` should be avoided.

Comment: I tried that however now it comes up with the error _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage4" doesn't exist     -     Im not sure what that means?

Comment: Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\rhysd\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Tkinter\CBG_Save_Prebuild_Screen.py", line 66, in SaveScreen
    picture1 = Label(window2, image=img3, text = "Label")
  File "C:\Users\rhysd\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2766, in __init__

Comment: Widget.__init__(self, master, 'label', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\rhysd\AppData\Local\Programs\Thonny\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage4" doesn't exist

Comment: That is the full error i get (it was too long to put as one comment)

Comment: that error comes because u r using a `Tk()` instance, so your `window2 = Tk()` should be changed to `window2 = Toplevel()`. This will most likely fix the error. And is the gap after .png purposefully given or a mistake while formatting code here?`img3 = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\Tkinter\ComputerImage.png ")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you used multiple instances of `Tk()` (one for first window, one for second window), you need to specify the parent for `picture1` and `img3`:

```
img3 = PhotoImage(master=window2, file=r"C:\Tkinter\ComputerImage.png")
picture1 = Label(window2, image=img3)
picture1.pack()
```

However, you should avoid using multiple instances of `Tk()`.  Better change second instance of `Tk()` to `Toplevel()`.

Answer (score 0):

Hey you forgot to mention the window name in `picture1 = Label(image=img3)`

here is the right one the mistake

```
# this is the part for the image    
img3 = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\\Tkinter\\ComputerImage.png ")
picture1 = Label(window2,image=img3)
picture1.pack()
```

And the
`error error _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage4" doesn't exist -`
You have to use `Toplevel()` in second window

```
window2=Toplevel ()
```

It works for me

Comment: Thanks for the reply, the error error _tkinter.TclError: image "pyimage4" doesn't exist is still there should i post the code for the first window would that help?

Comment: Try this one by giving ```\\``` in your file path ```img3 = PhotoImage(file=r"C:\\Tkinter\\ComputerImage.png ")```

Comment: @UjjwalDash why is there a space after .png? couldnt it be cauing the error?